#  Debugging jQuery plugin -- worked in 1.4, doesn't seem to work in 1.7

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm doing some work with a JQuery plugin that counts down text in a textarea box as users enter it. For some reason the plugin is not working as I expect.

I'm a reasonable javascript developer, but haven't built a plugin before. I'm trying to debug this one and figure out why it's not working.

The plugin describes itself as being tested with jQuery 1.3.x and 1.4.x. I have to use 1.7.1.

I've been able to trace into this portion of the plugin using `alert()`'s -- I can see the processing goes to a certian point, but doesn't seem to be proceeding. Or I may be misreading it as I'm still learning how to debug jQuery plugins.

In the code snippet I've added comments to where I can get `alert`s to work from and where I can't.

```
$.fn.NobleCount = function(c_obj, options) {
    var c_settings;
    var mc_passed = false;

    // if c_obj is not specified, then nothing to do here
    if (typeof c_obj == 'string') {

        // check for new & valid options
        c_settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.NobleCount.settings, options);

        // was max_chars passed via options parameter? 
        if (typeof options != 'undefined') {
            mc_passed = ((typeof options.max_chars == 'number') ? true : false);
        }


                    // THIS ALWAYS FIRES
                    console.log("I am here");

        // process all provided objects
        this.each(function(){

                           // THIS NEVER FIRES
                           console.log("I DON'T SEEM TO EVER EXECUTE");

            var $this = $(this);

            // attach events to c_obj
            attach_nobility($this, c_obj, c_settings, mc_passed);
        });
    }

    return this;
};
```

The code in the `attach_nobility` function never seems to run.

Has something changed from jquery 1.4 to jquery 1.7 that makes this work different?

EDIT: Here's the link to the [original NobleCount jquery plugin](http://tpgblog.com/noblecount/) page

EDIT: I'm calling the plugin like this:

```
(function() {

  $('#how_to_improve_input').NobleCount('#how_to_improve_count');

}).call(this);
```

Comment: Note: I've already confirmed that the jquery selector I'm attaching this to is a valid selector.

Comment: What is this when you console.log/dir it?

Comment: console.log(this); gives `[]`. Which I guess explains a lot. Has how `this` is passed changed for plugins since 1.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think the problem is with the plug-in. I did a basic one with the same pattern as in the code you provided.

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.foo = function (c_obj, options) {
        var c_settings;
        var mc_passed = false;
        if (typeof c_obj == 'string') {
            c_settings = $.extend({}, {a:"xxxx"}, options);
            console.log("aaaa");
            this.each(
                function(){
                    console.log("I DON'T SEEM TO EVER EXECUTE");
                    var $this = $(this);
                }
            );
        }
        return this;
    };
})( jQuery );
```

If I run it with a simple selector

```
jQuery("div").foo("asdf");
```

I get tons of log messages since it goes into the each loop.

If I do it with

```
jQuery("sfsdfdiv").foo("asdf");
```

It still goes into the function even though there are no elements. I see "aaaa" in the console. So you need to look at the selector and not the plug-in.